# How to make a photo of an eye looke like it's bloodshot?

Tags: photo-editing

I am a beginner in Photoshop, so I need some help. Can anyone please tell me how to replace `rgb` or `hsb` of a certain region?

I need to convert image 1 as the image 2 so that the veins look like in image 1. I am using photoshop cs6. I am a beginner so please describe the full process. Please help and thanks in advance.

[image][image]

Comment: I tried normal photoshop tools like color picker, replace etc but they can't give me the result that i desire. @scott sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many methods to this pretty simple task.

I don't think you need to adjust the actual veins of the eye, I would suggest just creating another layer above your eye image, set it to about 10-20% opacity and use the paintbrush tool with about 60% hardness and colour in the whites of the eye red.

Adjust the opacity of the layer if you're not happy with the result.

**STEP-BY-STEP:**

```
1. Create new layer:
```

[image]

```
2. Choose your brush:
```

[image]

```
3. Make your brush red:
```

[image]

```
4. change the hardness and size of your brush:
```

[image]

```
5. colour over the white of the eye on the new layer:
```

[image]

Then just adjust the layer opacity to get your desired red level.

Comment: Sir i can't get the result as you? I want the result like you to be reddened like the image that i gave above. @saturn

Comment: Sir can you please give me the image that you customize? @ saturn

Comment: @NiajulHasan I'm not just going to do the work for you. I've given you a very simple step-by-step process to follow. If you still can't follow that, I suggest you learn the basics of Photoshop.

Comment: I already tried but can't change like you.